# problem with simple templatetags usage in django

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

I try to use templatetags in django but I have trouble.
I defined `enumhelper.py` in the templatetags package.
Then I load it at the top of `employer_list.html` like

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load enumhelper %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
```

Content of `enumhelper.py` is really simple.

```
register = template.Library()

@register.tag()
def enum_worker_number_range():
    return "sdsdsd"
```

Then I want to use `enum_worker_number_range` in the `employer_list.html` as

```
{% block enumhelper %}
    {{ enum_worker_number_range }}
{% endblock %}
```

I expect to write `sdsdsd` at the page but I couldn't see anything. I am sure that load opearition is sucessful beacuse when I change `enumhelper` name it gives error.

Although load operation is successful, why I can't see the return value of  `enum_worker_number_range` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@register.simple_tag
def enum_worker_number_range():
    return "sdsdsd"
```

Comment: also since `enum_worker_number_range` is a tag, in template you have to write `{% enum_worker_number_range %}`